# How to sort monthly data from dates using R?

Tags: r, group-by, grouping

[image: Part of my dataset]

This is airline dataset from 2014 to 2018 with several Carriers flying on a certain date.

**From this, I want a count of the CANCELLATION - which is a column with only binary data, where 0- not canceled and 1- canceled, grouped by OP_CARRIER, monthly.**

I am new to R. I am able to just do these operations separately like the count using table(), and group by for OP_CARRIER.

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is this the flights data set?

Comment: @HanselPalencia yes, its only partly visible here. It has 23 columns and about 17M rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make a month column (I am assuming your date column is currently just a string).

```
df %>% mutate(FL_DATE = as.POSIXct(FL_DATE) %>%
   mutate(month= format(FL_DATE,"%B") %>%
   group_by(month, OP_CARRIER) %>%
   summarise(cancelations = sum(CANCELLATION))
```

this will do everything per month over multiple years so if you want per year add 
`mutate(year= format(FL_DATE,"%Y"))` in there and edit the 
`group_by(month, year, OP_CARRIER)`

Comment: Ahh he wanted it per month, nice catch

Comment: @jeffverboon, Hello. Thanks a lot. How would it be different if my FL_DATE is in date format? Will that make it easier?

Comment: I made it into a date format on the fly ( i added a year column too or you will sum up flights in jan in 2014 and 2015 etc which may or may not be what you want)

Comment: @jeffverboon that makes it so much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is `rowsum` in `base R` as `CANCELLATION` is a binary variable

```
rowsum(df1$CANCELLATION, group = df1$OP_CARRIER)
```

---

In `dplyr`.  If we also need `month`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    group_by(OP_CARRIER, month = month(as.Date(FL_DATE))) %>%
    summarise(CANCELLATION = sum(CANCELLATION))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(carrier, cancellation, month = month(as.Date(FL_DATE)) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```